# Based on scroll position how would I get an element to start following (fixed position) at 50px and then stop following at 2000px?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, position

I have an image that needs to be relative or absolute positioned to begin with, then starts following after a little scrolling and then sticks again on the page before the user continues down into another section. I've been using something like this but the script obviously conflicts with itself:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset <= 50){
        jQuery('.stickem').css({position: 'absolute', top: '50px' });
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.stickem').css({position: 'fixed', top: '50px'});
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 2040){
        jQuery('.stickem').css({position: 'absolute', top: '2040px' });
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.stickem').css({position: 'fixed', top: '2040px'});
    }
}
});
</script>
```

I basically just need class "fixed" applied if >= 50px but <= 2040px. Is there a way to write that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var fixedClassName = 'fixed';
    var absoluteClassName = 'absolute';
    var $window = jQuery(window);
    var $stickem = jQuery('.stickem');

    $window.on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > 2040) {

            if ($stickem.hasClass(fixedClassName)) {
                $stickem.removeClass(fixedClassName);
            }

            if (!$stickem.hasClass(absoluteClassName)) {
                $stickem.addClass(absoluteClassName);
            }

        } else if (scrollTop >= 50 && scrollTop <= 2040) {

            if (!$stickem.hasClass(fixedClassName)) {
                $stickem.addClass(fixedClassName);
            }

            if ($stickem.hasClass(absoluteClassName)) {
                $stickem.removeClass(absoluteClassName);
            }

        } else if ( $stickem.hasClass(fixedClassName) ) {

            $stickem.removeClass(fixedClassName);
            $stickem.removeClass(absoluteClassName);

        }
    });

});
```

Here's a fiddle if you want to play around with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rgvap3jh/

Add styling to the `.fixed` and `.absolute` classes as needed.

Comment: thanks. i think the problem is still when i'm 2,000px down the page and that class gets removed the image disappears. since it's no longer fixed it goes back up to the top i supposed where it was before it was fixed. it doesn't become part of the page and stay absolute at 2,000px.

Comment: @ZakKarst – So just to be super clear, after a 2040px the image needs to be absolutely positioned (not fixed)?

Comment: Yeah, it can't be fixed at the top or the drop slider covers it and it can't be fixed after 2040px but it needs to be "dropped off" at that location, not disappear back to the top.

Comment: @ZakKarst – See the updated answer. The jsfiddle link is also updated if you need to see the changes visually. Hope that helps.